# How to remove sensitive permissions to allow for app update google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

For a couple of months, I tried updating an app. The thing is I wanted to use the SMS permissions.

To do I had to fill the sensitive permission form in google play console.

After doing that, my app was rejected.

Fast forward, I decided to take my app project a different route.
I don't need the Sms functionality anymore.

I have removed the permissions from my android manifest, bump my app version. Uploaded a new version and only for it to be rejected for the same permission reason.
[image]

Which I thought was weird because I am not seeking the permissions anymore for my app.

I checked the App Content tab, and I could see that there is some permission stuff still going on with my app.
[image]

Unfortunately, for some unknown reason, Google isn't offering any means of deactivating or removing the permissions from the play console.

I am unable to update my app for this reason.
I have tried to make contact with the play team, but they haven't gotten back to me for some reason.

I am wondering if there is a fix for this?
I have tried all that I could find online on the permission problem but nothing has seemed to work out.
[image]

Comment: Go to Manage and check "View app bundles and APK" to see if the correct updated version is having these permissions.

Comment: i think this is helping: ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>```

Comment: If you can attach the screenshot for the same it will be more helpful.

Comment: I added another snapshot. Thank you.

Comment: @LearnToday have you found a solution? I am stucking in the same problem and I am not able to update my app for two weeks. All sensitive permissions are removed, but Google says my declaration is wrong.

Comment: @LearnToday have you found any solution to this problem? I also want a solution for the same.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same issue. It turns out, it's because I had an old APK that still used that permission in another release track. The trick is to upload new APKs to all release tracks that have old APKs in them.

Here's the article that provides more details: [Dear Google’s Permissions Declaration Form, Can We Break Up?](https://medium.com/@bapspatil/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690)

Comment: This was real solution for me... Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't remove the old APK which is using this permission because that is the current/live.

Comment: Even after I remove the permission from Manifest again the build is rejected, your answer helped.

Comment: Do I have to push the new app in production as well, or pushing the latest app to the testing track app is enough?

Comment: Your link solved the issue for me! Whilst Google play support was the opposite of useful.

Comment: How to delete previous rejected version of my app? Can't edit app content sensitive permission.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be resolved by removing sms, call permissions from manifest and create signed apk/bundle again for uploading to playstore.

Try to examine **Artifact library** in your play console. Click on version code's  down arrow of apk/bundle file and check for required permissions section, are still able to see call,sms permissions? If yes, you need to check manifest file again and remove sensitive permissions.

Comment: So, I have gone through my libraries, I realized the SMS library was requesting the permission. I removed that from the SMS package. let me try again, fingers crossed.

Comment: All the best, just go through the steps I have shared, before publish your app. If it does not contain sms or call permissions there you can submit it without any fear.

Comment: Is it possible that the read and write contacts are sensitive permissions too?

Comment: No read write do not comes under sensitive permissions

Comment: Does location permission lies under critical permissions? or background location?

Answer (score 0):

You also can get your app approved without uploading a new APK/AAB, just go to App content scroll down and find Sensitive permissions and APIs and change your declaritions and submit your app for review and Google will send it in production.