# Google Play rejects app even after removing sensitive permission from app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Our app on Google Play has been rejected because it used sensitive permission `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`.

Firstly we filled permission declaration form but it has been rejected. So we decided to remove this permission from our app.

We uploaded a new APK without this permission but again it has been rejected.

Why it has been rejected? In the google response there is a message:

> We found issues in the following areas 
> APK 1 
> APK 5 
> ... and so on

Why old apk's are listed there? These APKs are on closed testing tracks but all tests have been paused (Is there any option to delete these tracks? Maybe we should delete them but [as I can see here, it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737970/remove-internal-testing-release)). I read these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70111717/13363205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69933431/13363205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321821/20598102
- https://bapspatil.medium.com/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690

Am I correct that on every track we should upload a new version of an app without this permission so the error will be gone and we will be able to upload new app? Or maybe there is any other better option to do it?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: You need to replace the APKs on all tracks. Even if you've stopped the rollout, they're still available to some users which is why it's a problem

Answer (score 0):

I am currently stuck in the same problem, and here is what I finally did.

1. Fix all the issues that they mentioned in the emails they sent you.
2. Create a new build with increased version code and version number.
3. Wait for the previous review process in the play console to get rejected in all tracks.
   Note: Don't upload the new version until the previous review rejects your app.
4. After rejection, upload the new version and then create a new release in each track (Internal, Open, Closed and Production).

Finally, wait and hope for the best. If everything goes right your app will be published.

Method 2: After fixing everything, change the package name of your app and create a new app in the play console and publish it there.
To change the package name of your app follow this: [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)